# Get parts of DOCUMENT_URI using regex and SSI

Tags: regex, apache, bnf, ssi

I'm using Apache 2.4 and Server Side Includes.

When I use this:

```
<!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

It returns: `/foo/bar/file.html`

I want to capture the parts of the URI, i.e.:

```
  <!--#if expr='v("DOCUMENT_URI") =~ [\/\\](.+)[\/\\](.+)[\/\\](.+)[.]'-->
    <!--#set var='URI_PART1' value='$1' -->
    <!--#set var='URI_PART2' value='$2' -->
    <!--#set var='URI_PART3' value='$3' -->
  <!--#else -->
  <!--#endif -->
```

I have tried a lot of variations, but cannot get Apache to recognise the regex at all, in any way.  I was expecting "foo", "bar" and "file" to be recorded but instead receive the error [an error occurred while processing this directive].

I know the syntax has changed since Apache 2.4 and the above is what I've come up with based on my understanding of the new syntax..

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well, have a look at http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/10/29/reading-querystring-variables-using-server-side-includes-and-regular-expressions/. It is possible that all you need is to use `/^(.*)\./` regex and set the variable as `<!--#set var="mypath" value="$1" -->` (maybe you can add the slash after `$1`, if not, concatenate later.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried the following:
[code] <!--#set var="$DOCUMENT_URI value=/^(.*)\./"--> 
and some variations but it said [an error occurred while processing this directive]. I read there's a new syntax in Apache 2.4 but I'm not sure if that's the issue as other directives work fine..

Comment: That is strange, I do not know why that issue occurs. The pattern is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is reported as a bug, but un-resolved: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57448

There is a workaround as demonstrated in comment 8, to extract single values via $0, by adding this fragment:

```
&& $1 =~ /(.*)
```

which maps $1 to $0 as $0 is properly exported.

So you would have to extract your parts one at a time.

The other workaround is to enable and work with SSILegacyExprParser

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a lot of pre- Apache 2.4 documentation out there which is very confusing.

The answer is that you cannot isolate $1, $2, etc. parts your matched expression UNLESS it is to be used in another #if expression.

i.e. you cannot #set a new variable with $1 part of the string.

Not sure why this functionality is no longer possible, but yeah. There you go.